# Using PHP Sessions to save form data

Tags: php, forms, session

I have created a small quiz in PHP, that asks you a series of yes/no questions and then tells you the answer at the end. I am trying to use PHP sessions so that if the user only gets half way through the quiz, for example then when they close their browser and re-open it it will be on the same question as when they left. Below is the code for one of the forms I am using.

```
<div class='questions'>
  <form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
    <input type='submit' name='answer$number' value='Yes' class='buttons' />
    <input type='submit' name='answer$number' value='No' class='buttons' />
  </form>
</div>
```

If you want to see the quiz go to [s504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php](http://s504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php)
. I am not sure how to do this though as I haven't used sessions before, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: **$)$** (aka 404 while holding the `SHIFT` key)

Comment: I don't understand, where do I put that?

Comment: your link not exist [link](http://504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php).if you want to save the data, need set them in session , also you can use cookie for your aim,add more info about what u really want to do? which html element you have in your form?

Comment: sorry the link is s504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php. The main aim I want to achieve is so that when the user closes their browser, when they re-open the browser they will be at the same as when they left it

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this using PHP sessions because a session is destroyed when the browser is closed.

To achieve what you mention you should save the end-user's answers into a cookie and check for its existence when the page is initially loaded.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are registered, store it in a db. That's usually the best bet. Cookies can work but u have a chance of something going wrong.

Also - if i read correctly, answer `$number` doesn't concat in single quotes. would either be:

`echo " name='answer$number' "` (echo'd in double quotes) OR `echo 'name="answer'.$number.' " '` (echo'd in single quotes). this is frugal, nonetheless could be misleading. I spaced the quotes to indicate the gap, these however should pref be deleted.

I believe a db is the SAFEST way. U can always use a cookie to link a user to their answers. Also - a db will give u stats later. This way even if a user loses their cookie somehow they can always enter their email address to continue.

And yes, sessions are ALWAYS killed when the browser closes (just to confirm).